# Counterexamples in quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I'm looking for counterexamples in quantum theory, in the spirit of books like *Counterexamples in topology* and *Counterexamples in analysis*. A practically identical post, but for PDEs, can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68680/counterexamples-in-pde).

This request will probably be clearer to people who have read those books: I am **not** looking for claimed 'disproofs' of quantum theory by cranks, but rather examples from quantum theory that defy intuition or expectation, or which 'break' theorems that we would otherwise want to hold, and in the process help clarify some of the theory's more subtle issues. Also note that I am not looking for ways in which quantum theory deviates from classical physics, like the tunneling effect or the blackbody spectrum.

A good example might be a strange solution to the Schrodinger equation, or to the Dirac equation in a particular field, or maybe something like the [Haag–Lopuszanski–Sohnius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%E2%80%93Lopuszanski%E2%80%93Sohnius_theorem), etc.

Comment: To be clear: are you asking for mathematical constructions in the framework of quantum theory (i.e. the $1/r^2$ potential which has some bizarre properties), or physically realized examples? +1 for the idea though - love the counterexamples series!

Comment: Either one would be fine. I think a good "physically realized example" from, say, optics, might be the fact (only recently discovered) that you can have [fractal laser modes](http://www.cse.salford.ac.uk/profiles/gsmcdonald/FractalLasers.php). I'm not sure what that would be a counterexample to, though, but it's the sort of head-turning "seriously? that's possible?" thing I'm after.

Comment: I'd like to hear about the 1/r^2 potential. Maybe you could elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew - unfortunately list questions like this are not appropriate for this site. You could try to collect some ideas in [chat] though.

Comment: :( I am sorry to hear that.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I agree that this question is too dangerous to attract  crackpots .... But I hope you are not going to close now every question that asks about an example in some context. That would be really silly. Maybe the definition of a list question should be clarified in meta, it is applyed y too randomly and subjective and dependent on personal opinions these days. That one is no lon

Comment: @AndrewGibson check this book out: http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Paradoxes-Physics-Textbook-Aharonov/dp/3527403914

Comment: @MarkMitchison Ooh sounds nice!

Comment: @MarkMitchison Nice, that's exactly the sort of stuff I was looking for. Bohm-Aharonov is a great example!